# Check user group of already logged in user in KeyCloak

Tags: authentication, keycloak

I have two application, both are using keycloak to authenticate user of the same realm. I've created two different client, and two different user group. Only users of a specific group can access to corresponding application.
I'm using this [custom](https://github.com/thomasdarimont/keycloak-extension-playground/tree/master/auth-require-group-extension) extension to verify user group after user login. I've created two different user flow based on **Browser Flow**, one for group, and I've configurated each client to use the relative user flow. This is working fine when a user tries to login.

I'm giving an example to better explain:
I have two group A and B. One user belongs to group A. When the user isn't logged, he can access to application A but he can not access to application B.

**What I cannot prevent is user access to application B when he is already logged into application A.**
This is happening because Browser Flow has a cookie step that gives authorization of users already logged.

Is there a step to check user group (or other user information) after the cookie step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution:
I created a new authentication flow, at first level I've created a sub flow containg the standard Browser Flow and always at first level I've added the execution of group verification.

Both step at first level are marked as required.

[image: Group Flow]